# js target first li of inner ul

Tags: javascript, element

I have an event listener on the li that says 'about us'.  How do I target or get the element corresponding to the li that says 'one'

```
<li class="aboutUs" onmouseover="showUl('aboutUs')" onmouseleave="hideUl()">about us
   <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
    </ul> 
 </li>
```

js:

```
aboutUs = document.getElementsByClassName('aboutUs')[0]  


aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
newColor(event)
}, {
passive: false
})
```

even.target when I console.log give me:

```
<li class="aboutUs" onmouseover="showUl('aboutUs')" onmouseleave="hideUl()">… 
</li>
```

so I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Do you want the first-child of the ul, or the first li containing the string "one"?

Comment: firstChild would be great

Comment: And please add the code you already have to add an eventlistener to the first one. So we know what kind of framework you are using etc. It's a simple task of modifying the selector

Comment: Thanks for including the code. You're probably looking for [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). I'm curious as to what you're trying to do here. As your function is called `newColor(...)`, I feel like it should be pointed out that you can (and should) do hover style changes in CSS instead of JS where possible.

Comment: querySelector did the trick.  Thanks.  I'm trying to reproduce a problem I'm having in wordpress with multiple mouseover listeners.  admittedly this example is a little odd but I think it will demonstrate my actual problem when I'm finished